# Access to a types, supported in PCL from a T4 template

Tags: c#, reflection, t4, portable-class-library

I have a PCL (Portable Class Library) project with T4 template inside. In a T4 template I need to iterate all types from mscorlib; but only types, that supported in PCL - I use these types in a generated code. How can I do it?

I was tried next:

```
const string Root = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable";
const string Version = "v4.6";
var assemblyPath = Path.Combine(Root, Version, "mscorlib.dll");

// v1 - "types" is empty array
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(assemblyPath);
var assembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(bytes);
var types = assembly.GetTypes();

// v2 - "types" contains non-PCL types, like System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyPath);
var types = assembly.GetTypes();
```

Is there a way to iterate only PCL types, except querying MSDN for each type and parse it? :о)

Comment: Try System.Runtime.dll instead of mscorlib if you are using v4.5 or above for the version.

Comment: @DanielPlaisted Thanks! But, this is not working or I can not understand how should I load this library. When I just change "mscorlib" to a "System.Runtime" in my sample I get an empty types array in both cases.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?  Myself, I am iterating over types within a PCL assembly, auto-generating extension methods.   I have issues with using anything related to Reflection, getting errors like cannot convert from 'System.Type [c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll]' to 'System.Type'   -- I think it has to do with the T4 template referencing the PCL types, and there being an incompatibility between the runtimes for T4 and the PCL??   Still working on it, just curious if you ever found a solution.

Comment: @TravisWhidden I have the exactly same task (generating extension methods) and I don`t find any solution.

Comment: I ended up just gunking up my T4 template with type names instead of passing the .net objects.   Worked for what I needed, though its was not optimal.